# MOSFET heats up quickly in High power 14V DC-DC bidirectional charging circuit

Tags: diodes, battery-charging, powermosfet, lifepo4, bidirectional

I am currently design the following circuit to charge a 14V LifePO4 4 cells battery while running a high power motor at 14V 24A. There are some issues that I am currently facing:

- Without any diodes and MOSFETs, charging current is 9.6A but after I install the following circuit, the system only charge at maximum 5.6A. I suspect that current is lost after flowing through the diode but is there any other reason behind this. [image]
- When I hooked up the system without buck converter and operate the Thruster with PWM using potentiometer to control speed, the MOSFET M2 get hot in a very short time. What maybe the cause for this.

Sorry for the dark picture and thank you for all of your response.

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be anything driving the gates. Please make the effort to fix up your schematic.

Comment: Your schematic looks great but with black on black it is very difficult to read. Anything you can do to fix it?

Comment: Please explain how this circuit is supposed to work.

Comment: Gate drive voltage probably incorrect. Please research NMOS high side gate drive circuits.